# Can a sharepoint 2007 site access accounts from 2 domains?

Tags: domain, authentication

I have 2 domains.

DOGS and CATS (for example)

The sharepoint server is a member of DOGS. Can I get the sharepoint site/web app/server to also reference domain accounts from CATS?

So I add users like:

```
CATS\Group1
DOGS\Group2
CATS\Administrator
DOGS\Administrator
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Steve said, you'll need to have a cross-forest trust in place to accomplish this. You'll need Domain Admin credentials to do it in Active Directory (it's not something you do in SharePoint). Here's a link to an article for Server 2003, though the process shouldn't be *that* much different if you're on 2008.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc780479(WS.10).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you have a two way trust (or one-way depending on needs) setup between the two domains.

Comment: How can I setup a one way trust?